# Can't see dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta8 option when publishing

Tags: asp.net-core

When I publish source code web API (ASP.NET 5), I can't see dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta8 option in Target DNX Version dropdown list while my friends can see this option on their computers. Please help me.

Comment: Please update to RC1.

Comment: Probably you don't have the beta8 runtime installed. As commented by @poke - update to RC1 - and this is not only about the runtime but also the tooling.